# Upload a zip to a arcgis server geoprocessing service using php and cURL library

Tags: php, php-curl, arcgis-server

I'm trying to upload a zip file using php and cURL library at https://landfiredev.cr.usgs.gov/arcgis/rest/services/Script1/GPServer/uploads/upload but the file doesn't get uploaded.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for your help.

**Here's my code:**

```
$LCPRequest = "https://landfiredev.cr.usgs.gov/arcgis/rest/services/Script1/GPServer/uploads/upload";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $LCPRequest);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$cfile = curl_file_create('D:\Services\shapefiles\shapefiles.zip','application/zip','shapefiles.zip');
$requestParameters = array('file'=>$cfile, 'f'=>'pjson', 'description'=>'sample');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($requestParameters));

$output = curl_exec($ch);

print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));

curl_close($ch);

echo $output . "\r\n";
```

**And here's my output:**

```
Array
(
    [url] => https://landfiredev.cr.usgs.gov/arcgis/rest/services/Script1/GPServer/uploads/upload
    [content_type] => text/plain;charset=UTF-8
    [http_code] => 200
    [header_size] => 616
    [request_size] => 436
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 20
    [redirect_count] => 0 
    [total_time] => 0.266
    [namelookup_time] => 0.125
    [connect_time] => 0.157
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.219
    [size_upload] => 166  
    [size_download] => 99  
    [speed_download] => 372  
    [speed_upload] => 624  
    [download_content_length] => 99  
    [upload_content_length] => 166  
    [starttransfer_time] => 0.266   
    [redirect_time] => 0   
    [redirect_url] =>
    [primary_ip] => 152.61.128.29
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_port] => 443
    [local_ip] => xxxxxxxx
    [local_port] => 50416
)

 


{
 "error": {
  "code": 500,
  "message": "Error performing upload operation",
  "details": []
 }
}
```